# PHP Excel does not export more than 11000 rows

Tags: php, export, phpexcel

[image]I am trying to export more than 11000 rows in PHP Excel, its working great till 11000 after it, when I am trying to export it mix all rows.

Comment: _it mix all rows.._ What are rows? Are you talking about csv import from php to excel?

Comment: I am talking about exporting data from database in xls format.

Comment: still no idea what you are trying to ask...

Comment: I have huge HTML table about 15000 rows. When I want to export that table to xls in PHP Excel , after 11000 rows it mix all rowspans.

Comment: Ok... post the relavant partt of the code please and lets find out what the issue is... but I think your data is broken (after 11000th record) Is it exactly 11000?

Comment: Here is screenshot
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al0R0.png

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly this is a timeout or a memory issue. The only PHPExcel limit for worksheets size is 65,536 rows and 256 (IV) columns (when using the Excel5 Writer); or 1,048,576 rows and 16,384 (XFD) columns (when using the Excel2007 Writer).

Ensure that your error logging is always enabled... use try/catch blocks to trap for any PHPExcel Exceptions. And read the PHPExcel site discussion threads on memory and performance.